# Copy Analysis Services Cube?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssas, olap, cube

I haven't been able to find anything on this but is there a way to copy a cube within Visual Studio 2008?
I want to make changes to a cube but the only system access I have is to a production system and I would like to make a custom version of the cube without changing the model version.  Thoughts?

Thank you in advance, John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually not done in Visual Studio, but using Sql Server Management Studio.

Connect to the SSAS server using Sql Server Management Studio.

Right click the OLAP database name and script it out as XMLA.

Change the Database Id and Database Name (lines 5 and 6) to MyOlapDb_New

Deploy the script (press <kbd>F5</kbd>)

Now you have a copy that you can play with.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you Raj!

Comment: How to copy data?

Comment: @nicolay.anykienko backup and restore is the way to copy data plus structure.

Comment: @Raj More, yes I know. Just wanted to point out that your solution will not work for database with existing data.